# How to embed password in runas command?

Tags: windows, command-line

When I run this at the cmd:

```
runas /env /user:administrator "IECapt.exe --url=http://www.google.com/ --out=test.png"
```

it prompts for password.

How can I embed the password inside the command so that it does not prompt for the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/savecred` - option may be what you're searching.

Comment: It doesn't work on Vista Home or Starter, that's right. But since it's on Vista, why don't you use the "run as Administrator" in the file-properties->Compatibility tab (say on a .bat-file)? This way only the UAC-dialog is shown.