# Single line command for Run as a different user on Windows 7 that contains a password also

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there any single line command for Run As Different User in Windows 7.
I am using following command but then it ask for password

```
runas /user:USER-NAME "C:\full\path\of\Program.exe"
```

Is there any way to `supply password also` in above line ? Actually i am launching application from other application so I don't want any user interaction But in above command it ask user for `PASSWORD`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed password in runas command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825672/how-to-embed-password-in-runas-command)

Comment: Note a comment from Raymond Chen: ["If this offends you and you want to be insecure and pass the password on the command line anyway (for everyone to see in the command window title bar), you can write your own program that calls the CreateProcessWithLogonW function."](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041129-00/?p=37183)

Answer (score 11):

PsExec in the [MS SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) suite:

```
psexec -user Administrator -p Passwd "xcopy a.xml \\server_over_there\c$\A.xml"
```

Comment: -1 "PsExec executes a program on a remote computer" while the question asks how to execute a program locally... (as another user without entering a password manually, in script)

Comment: +1 for psexec. Contrary to what someone here seems to believe, it executes programs just fine on a local machine.

Comment: @Spadefinger:  Thx.  Here is usage from SysInternals.  First param (remote computer) is optional.  Default is local:         Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
-a

Comment: Good work! It's much more useful than RunAs which confines you under a 'security' hood.

Answer (score -3):

In case the local user is NOT what you need and a specific DOMAIN user is, use:

```
/user      Username in form USER@DOMAIN or DOMAIN\USER
           (USER@DOMAIN is not compatible with /netonly)
```